# Is it possible to twist a circle into a sphere?

Tags: animation, workflow, transforms

I'm wondering if something like this is possible to make in Blender:

[image]

This animation I found on [Dribble](https://dribbble.com/shots/1680920-Twisting-Circle-incl-project-file?list=buckets&offset=117) looks really amazing. The person who made it says it is done on Cinema 4D.

It looks like a string starting with a circular shape, then it is being twisted into a sphere with equal spacing in between. The sphere is then rotated and finally returning to its original circular shape.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Yes**.

There are probably multiple ways of doing this, but one way is to use a circle with a simple deform modifier set to *twist*, and using an empty as the twist origin:

[image]

By animating the rotation of both the circle and the empty, you can make it twist around, and by animating the deform angle, you can control the amount of twisting.

**Result:** (click for better quality)

[image]

[**Example .blend**](https://web.archive.org/web/20141009074909/http://www.pasteall.org:80/blend/31917)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there is a simple deform modifier and so I tried it right away in Blender. It generated a result almost identical to the gif! That's awesome, thanks. (You also mentioned there are other ways to achieve this effect. What would be some other methods to do it?)

Comment: I haven't thought of any that work yet, I just said that as a disclaimer that this is probably not the only way. I'll update the answer if I think of one :)

Comment: That's fine I don't really need that many ways just to create one effect anyway. By the way, this is [the one](http://imgur.com/f0rx6aC) I just made using your method, and here's [another one](https://dribbble.com/shots/1679976-Twisting-circle) I found that's not spinning like crazy. I realized that mine starts off facing up and later the poles are facing horizontally, however in the one I found the circles and the poles are always facing horizontally. I can't seem to recreate that (there's no option to change how it is twisted it seems).

Comment: That is controlled by the orientation of the empty. Example .blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31918. The amount of twisting is controlled by the angle in the modifier.

Comment: I know it is controlled by the empty, but no matter how it is rotated they just won't face the same direction.

Comment: Works fine for me. See the example .blend in my previous comment.

Comment: This is what I meant: http://i.stack.imgur.com/o9chW.png The two arrows aren't pointing at the same direction

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 But it stays consistent throughout the animation.. It's just as easy to make it vertical: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31921

Comment: I just downloaded your new blend file but unlike the one I mentioned ([this](https://dribbble.com/shots/1679976-Twisting-circle)) they are still not facing the same direction... I guess it is actually not possible but I'm actually fine with the effect I already got now. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Oh I see what you mean now.. It's quite possible, what they did was animate the rotation. Here's another .blend: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31924