# How would I twist a torus or circle into an infinity symbol?

Tags: modeling, animation, workflow

I can't seem to figure out how to create an animation of a zero twisting into an infinity symbol. I'm brand new to blender, and not really sure how to manipulate a torus to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16467/599

Comment: thanks! this got me on the right track, but I'm still pretty lost (I downloaded blender 2 days ago). I downloaded your "spinning_ball2" file, but am unsure on how to change the animation from a ball to just an infinity symbol. Sorry if I sound dumb!

Comment: Changing the maximum amount of twisting should work. I don't have time to write a complete answer atm, but here's a .blend with an example: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32315

Comment: wow, thank you very much! the blend example allowed me to see what different settings do. I appreciate the help!

Comment: If no longer a torus, what would this shape be called?

Answer (score 9):

One way would be to do something similar to [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16467/599), but with fewer twists.

I found that  100° twist with the **Simple Deform** modifier gives a pretty good infinity symbol when seen from a front view:

[image]

By animating the amount of twisting (you can hover over almost any UI element and press <kbd>I</kbd> to insert a keyframe), you can get a result like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: if no longer a torus, what would this shape be called?

Answer (score 4):

Quick solution I discovered as a new user:

1. Object Mode: Add->Curve->Circle
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> (edit mode) & <kbd>A</kbd> until everything is unselected
3. Select handles on opposite sides (say on the Y/green axis) and <kbd>X</kbd> to delete them
   (must be deleted as a pair to keep symmetry)
4. Select the END of one of the 2 remaining handles (on the X/red axis) and rotate 180°  <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> `180` <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. Optional: Select both handles with <kbd>A</kbd>, scale with: <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> `0.5` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Turn it into a tube:

1. Shape: Resolution: Preview U: increase to smooth curvature
2. Shape: 3D
3. Fill: Full
4. Geometry: Bevel: Depth: increase as desired
5. Geometry: Bevel: Resolution: increase to desired smoothness of tube
6. Active Spline: Smooth should be checked

Answer (score 2):

You could use *Shape Keys* in *Object Mode* add to shape keys in the mesh/Properties.

[image]

Switch to *Edit Mode* <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Select the vertices at the top and bottom (yellow) switch on proportional editing <kbd>O</kbd>, scale <kbd>S</kbd>,(adjust the influence as indicated by the white circle with your mouse wheel) constrain to y-axis <kbd>Y</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could make a bone twist one half of the torus. Sadly, the mesh near the middle gets really thin.

[image: Twising a zero into infinity in blender]

Comment: I think one of the laplacian modifiers is meant to help with that kind of thinning; don't have time to look farther right now.

Answer (score 1):

Torus as an infinity symbol:

1. Object Mode: Add->Curve->Circle
2. Object Mode: Add->Mesh->Torus (the circle will be hidden inside the torus -- Torus should be selected)
3. Add Modifier->Deform->Curve
4. Object: BezierCurve
5. Apply (leave Deformation Axis as `X` -- the result won't look right; but...)
6. <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Y</kbd> `-1`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

   Voila!

Comment: I actually really like this method. It was the easiest. Though the normals got messed up afterwards. I decided to use a full line in the finished torus and turned it into a curve and played with that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

### Geometry Nodes

just join the party here :) The [gandalf3's way](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18149/2214) if I can say that ... two points moved upward ... so just an optical illusion based on point of view :)

[image]
[image]

Another way to move control points up and down from object centre to easier change a shape and animate ...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: do you think possible to make the animation symmetrical in this case?

Comment: Sorry ... Do you see it asymmetrical now in this setup? Or I didn't get the point :)

Comment: I meant it looks like the left part flatten first or as if the left part is initiating the transition (not only your solution but 'all'). I was wondering if it is possible to do it so that both sides (left/right) are symmetrical?

Comment: Hm ... I have a problem to imagine how such thing moves (other than the stacker's answer.

Answer (score 0):

### Curve of two points

Curve Circle simplified into a two control points only ...

[image]

Each control point Hooked by Empty ... animate Empty rotation (and scale to fix curvature) ...

[image]

Note:

- I set under Curve Properties > Smooth 0.5 (if zero there was a geometry twist)
- with just two control points there is probably not possible to set more roundy shape of infinity

[image]