# Question from noob about twisting the curve

Tags: bezier-curves

Was unable to find an answer on the forum and google.

There is a simple curve (circle) and applied "Simple Deform" -> Twist -> 360° by X. Plus added a bit bevel depth in Geometry.

The shape and the cross-section become flattened. But is there a way to keep their initial circle shape like it would be a wire no matter what twisting angle is applied? ?

For example like [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16467/is-it-possible-to-twist-a-circle-into-a-sphere)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with a Curve > Circle, one way to do this would to be to arrange for the bevel of the curve to take place *after* the twist, using Geometry Nodes:

[image]

Below the *Twist* modifier on the stack, internally, the geometry is considered to be a Mesh, so has to be converted back to a curve in GN, before profiling:

[image]

If you're particular about the overall shape, it may be worth noting the *Twist* does not produce a perfect sphere from a circle, so you may want to insert a *Cast* modifier, (Sphere, Factor 1), below the *Twist*.

Here's a share:

[image]

Check out:

- The curve-circle has no Object-Mode scale. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to apply the scale if necessary)
- TIn the circle's own Data tab, it's been set to a high enough resolution to accommodate the curvature

Comment: Thank you very very much, Robin, for your time on this issue. At least I can see it is possible and people who know how to do this are alive. As I mentioned above I'm a noob in all this I tried to reproduce everything you described and showed but definitely missed something so I got [the following](https://imgur.com/a/Gi4vntA). Could you please point out where I could make a mistake?

Comment: @ВадимГусар See edit to my post for a share, and a couple of possible problems with your version.

Comment: Robin, thank you very much again. No doubt you are a wizard for me. The problem was that I still used bevel depth in "Object Data Property" -> Geometry, it should be 0 there. Once again, thank you very much, @Robin-Betts

Comment: @ВадимГусар No problem at all. If the answer has worked for you, you can click the tick next to it. That will mark it as 'solved' for other users.

Comment: Done, marked, and once again thank you, @Robin-Betts. Can you give me a favour and answer the last question? As I understand you provided me (and all the rest who need this) with the solution for the latest version of Blender where GeometryNodes was added. But as I understand from my link reference in the question there was a solution for previous versions without using nodes. Do you have any ideas about how they made this?

Comment: Hi, @ВадимГусар Fair question. I don't know whether  the dependency graph has changed since then?  As a mod I get to see deleted posts. A deleted 'answer' to your link was a misplaced supplementary question, complaining that the profile was coming out flat, in 2018. I've tried deforming a mesh cylinder along the twisted curve, but it doesn't pick up the twist..  I can't find a way.. I. too, would be interested in an answer to  this. Still having a think.

Comment: Hello, @Robin-Betts. Thank you for your time, help and sharing your knowledge with noobs :)